# Create items in Sitecore tree from a windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sitecore, sitecore6

I have a Sitecore web application where the development is almost completed. For testing purposes I have to populate the Sitecore tree with a large number of items. To populate the Sitecore tree I want to develop a .NET windows application, because I have to create more that 100,000 items and its going to take a long time.

But how could I connect to the API of the Sitecore application from the windows application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike Edwards has a good series of blog posts on [setting up unit tests](http://www.experimentsincode.com/?p=232) to run against a set of Sitecore databases, that is outside of IIS. You can use the information in these posts to understand what configuration files you will need to import for your windows application to able to call the Sitecore APIs without going through IIS. Note that you won't have a Sitecore context.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option here is to use the standard Sitecore Service to create your items. It is a SOAP webservice that you can connect to from your Windows application.

The service is available at the address: `http://<yourdomain>/sitecore/shell/webservice/service.asmx?WSDL`

See [this Sitecore document](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/Sitecore_Web_Service_SC65_A4.pdf) which describes the service and how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and its a new knowledge for me. But I already have a web page in the same application which does the same operation. Problem with that is after few 1000 items are created the IIS Worker Process's memory usage has increased and the application does not respond anymore.


With your web service approach I'm again doing the same thing via IIS and it will cause the same issue. I wonder whether there is another way to do this without going through IIS server. My Sitecore application and the windows application both are running on the same server machine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just create a simple page with one button, that creates the test items.

This is far easier  and not slower or anything.

Be sure to use the SecurityDisabler, ProxyDisabler and BulkUpdateContext.

Also disable indexing and as many events as possible.

Fix the memory leak you have, trigger GC to fix you memory issues. Posting the code here might reveal some issues ;-)

Comment: As the Kevin Obee's advice I'm now in a Windows application context and its far better than the web page performance.

But I have the memory leak in there in long run, you may refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602031/creating-big-amount-of-sitecore-items-causes-memory-leak question thread and can help me.